# Find the surface area of the surface formed by rotating the curve $x\:=\sqrt{81-y^2},\:0\:\le \:y\:\le \:6$ about the y-axis.

Tags: calculus

Find the surface area of the surface formed by rotating the curve $x\:=\sqrt{81-y^2},\:0\:\le \:y\:\le \:6$ about the y-axis. 
i started this question by setting it up with the equation
$\int _0^6\:2\pi x\sqrt{1+\frac{dx}{dy}^2}dy$ and plugged in the known information. $\int _0^6\:2\pi \left(\sqrt{81-y^2}\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{81-y^2}}dy$ if did the $\frac{dx}{dy}^2$ correctly, which i struggled with a lot. so i was wondering if i messed up there. but next i moved onto simplifying $\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{81-y^2}}$ and got stuck on $9\sqrt{\frac{1}{81-y^2}}$ , which i think is $csc\theta $ so now im left with $\int _0^6\:2\pi \left(\sqrt{81-y^2}\right)\cdot csc\theta \:dy$ and don't know what to do next or if i've been doing this problem correctly.

Answer (score 3):

A hint: the product of $\sqrt{81-y^2}$ and $\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{81-y^2}}$ happens to be a constant.

As an alternative, note that $x = \sqrt{81-y^2}$ is just the equation of a circle of radius 9, so the answer can be found as a fraction of the surface area of a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$9\sqrt{\frac{1}{81-y^2}}$$
foes have a shortcut. The integral
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}du=\arcsin\frac{a}{u}+C$$
Can you go from here?

Comment: so i get that i got csc . do i have to change the values of a and b now for the integral because i subbed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm stuck somewhere here, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is area of a segment of sphere as the given equation is that of a circle centered at (0,0).

As an exercise algebraically derive formula for a sphere $x^2+ y^2 = a^2$ between $ (y,0, y_{max})$ , it is simply $ 2 \pi a y_{max}$

Plug in $ a = 9$ and  $ y_{max}= 6 $.